# Right to left punctuation incorrect with arabic text wrapping

Tags: html, css, arabic, right-to-left

I have arabic text that displays correctly until the text starts to wrap.  I created a simple example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yodMjv

Here is the code:

```
<div style="width:400px">
<span style="direction: rtl; font-size: 26px;"> .نعم. عملت كمهندس في شركة مايكروسوفت لمدة خمس سنوات</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the second period is on the first line of text, when it should be on the second line of text.  If you take my code example and increase the width so that everything is on one line, the punctuation is correct.  This is only happening when the text wraps.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you might need also to reset [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi):

> The `unicode-bidi` CSS property, together with the direction property, determines how bidirectional text in a document is handled. For example, if a block of content contains both left-to-right and right-to-left text, the user-agent uses a complex Unicode algorithm to decide how to display the text. The `unicode-bidi` property overrides this algorithm and allows the developer to control the text embedding.

```html
<div style="width:400px">
<span style="direction: rtl; font-size: 26px;unicode-bidi: embed;"> .نعم. عملت كمهندس في شركة مايكروسوفت لمدة خمس سنوات</span>
</div>
```

see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/

Comment: This puts the period to the right of the sentence not to the left.

Comment: @Curtis unicode-bidi comes with many values : `unicode-bidi: embed;
unicode-bidi: isolate;
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
unicode-bidi: isolate-override;
unicode-bidi: plaintext;` ,  read the spec and use the proper value that fits your needs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RLbQLr since i can't read it, not too sure what fits the best :)

Comment: @Curtis to go further, you might want to read this if you did not yet